# Javascript object rendering only as last element in Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Why does the object below print only as the last element and not as the entire object? I would think it would print as {
id: 1,
id: 2,
id: 3,
}

https://codepen.io/kiggs1881/pen/JjwGKQG

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <h2>{{images}}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

 <script>
import {ref, onMounted, watch} from 'vue'
export default {
 setup(){
   const images = ref({})

 onMounted(()=>{
  images.value = {
    id: 1,
    id: 2,
    id: 3,
  };
  
})

return {
  images
   }
  }
};
```

Comment: object properties must be unique.  Given 3 `id` properties, the object only takes the last one given, `id: 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the object you provided prints only the last element is because object keys must be unique. When you define:

```
{
  id: 1,
  id: 2,
  id: 3,
}
```

It's the same as:

```
{
  id: 3,
}
```

When you set multiple keys with the same name, only the last one remains in the object. The preceding ones are overwritten.

If you intend to keep multiple values for id, you'd likely want an array:

```
images.value = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3},
];
```

Then, to display them, you can use a loop in your template:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h2 v-for="image in images" :key="image.id">{{ image.id }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>
```